# Select with different values in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to create a select box using jQuery's select2 with a list of options but with different values. Right now, the values are equal with what is being displayed.

For example, the option should say "Runner" while the value for that option should say "Runner - Individual". I cannot get an array of options to included the option's value.

```
.formfield
  = f.label :registration_type, "Select a registration type"
  = f.select :registration_type, options_for_registration, { :include_blank => true, :selected => session[:zombie_run].try(:[], :registration_type) }, { :class => 'required', :style => 'width: 16em;' }


def options_for_registration
    options = []
    today = Time.current.to_date
    if today <= @event.event_date
      options << 'Runner' unless @event.runner_waves.all?(&:full?)
      options << 'Team' unless @event.runner_waves.all?(&:full?) || @event.registration_closed?
      options << 'Zombie' unless @event.zombie_shifts.all?(&:full?)
      options << 'Volunteer' unless @event.volunteer_shifts.all?(&:full?)
    end

    options
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options << ['Runner - Individual', 'Runner'] unless @event.runner_waves.all?(&:full?)
# ...
```